# Apocope at beginning of sentence

Tags: clipping

When beginning a sentence with an apocopated word, does one capitalise the first letter printed--ie, the second or later letter of the word? Or does one just let the apostrophe stand for the absent capitalised letter?
Thank you.

Comment: Apocope is the omission of the _final_ sound of a word, so it would not affect the initial letter of a sentence. Perhaps you could supply an example of what you mean.

Comment: Like *'Twas brillig, and the slithy toves. / Did gyre and gimble in the wabe...*? Although I guess poetry may be different to some usages (capitalising first letter of every line as well as every sentence). Do you have a specific example?

Comment: If you started a sentence with *'Til* rather than *Until* or *Till*, it would still have a capital T.